# WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server

Tags: wayland, fish, setxkbmap

I'm using Fedora 37, tilix terminal emulator with fish shell.

Whenever I open a terminal, I get the warning

```
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an XWayland server
```

How come? How to avoid it?

Comment: Is it possible your configuration runs `setxkbmap` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a `setxkbmap` in my `.profile`. I found it by ripgrepping my home directory:
`rg --no-ignore --hidden setxkbmap ~`